# Can I use reserved keywords in NS_SWIFT_NAME?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to make an Objective-C delegate protocol prettier for use in Swift, and I'm running into some trouble figuring out how to use `NS_SWIFT_NAME`. Is it possible to use `NS_SWIFT_NAME` to specify parameters in the Swift name that have the same name as an Objective-C keyword (specifically `for` and `in`)?

This doesn't build:

```
@protocol MyContainerDelegate
  -(NSInteger)myContainerContentsCount:(MyContainer *)container
    NS_SWIFT_NAME(contentsCount(in container:));
@end
```

but if I declare it as `NS_SWIFT_NAME(contentsCount(inContainer:))` it works.

I'm pretty sure I've seen Swift methods that have `for` or `in` for their external parameter names, but I don't know where to find an example definition of such. Can this be done with `NS_SWIFT_NAME`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the keyword, but that you specified both argument
label and parameter name in `NS_SWIFT_NAME`. The argument label
is sufficient. With

```
@protocol MyContainerDelegate
-(NSInteger)myContainerContentsCount:(MyContainer *)container
    NS_SWIFT_NAME(contentsCount(in:));
@end
```

the protocol is exported to Swift as

```
public protocol MyContainerDelegate {
    public func contentsCount(in container: MyContainer!) -> Int
}
```