# Xcode forcing me to use cameCase for Objc++ function names

Tags: swift, objective-c++

I wanted to test out forking in a macOS swift command line app. Since the linux [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) method is C++, there needs to be Objc++ bridge header.

Here's my sample app:

In main.swift file,

```
import Foundation

var gReturnValue = main ()
print("Return value = \(gReturnValue)\n")


func main () -> Int {

    var pid:Int
    
    pid = ForkNewSession.StartFork()
    
    if (pid < 0) {
        
        NSLog("Fork failed!!")
        return -1
    } else if (pid != 0) {
        
        NSLog("Parent Process!! Exiting!")
        return 1
    }
    
    NSLog("Child Process!!")
        
    return 0;
}
```

ForkNewSession is an ObjC++ class registered in the bridge header (thus, available in swift).

```
@interface ForkNewSession : NSObject

+ (NSInteger) StartFork;

@end
```

But Xcode build fails with this error:

[image]

I'm new to swift and app development with swift. I don't know why this is happening?
Previously, I had used ObjC++ and C++ and there was no trouble there.

Does swift not allow functions which don't use camelCase? Or is there something else?

Comment: Without using an attribute to specify a specific name, the Objective C importer will try it’s best to convert identifiers so they follow the conventions in Swift. Even in Objective C, this name would be unconventional. Method selectors are expected to start with a lower case letter. UpperCamelCase is reserved for class names.

Comment: @Alexander, "Without using an attribute to specify a specific name" - Can you elaborate this with an example? Even if its not a convention, I'd like to use PascalCase.

Comment: “Even if its not a convention, I'd like to use PascalCase” I would really strongly advise against that. Especially if you’re post code snippets online to get help, you’ll have to lower case them (if you want people to understand you, which you probably do). To any seasoned Swift developer, `ForkNewSession.StartNewFork()` will look like the instantiation of a new object of a type `StartNewFork` nested in `ForkNewSession`. Anyway, here’s some rope in case you’re adamant: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/renaming-objective-c-apis-for-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does swift not allow functions which don't use camelCase? Or is there something else?

I don't think it's reliably known (outside of development team responsible for that) why the interoperability generator was implemented this way. UpperCamelCase method names in Swift are neither reserved nor prohibited by Swift language, however such approach is quite inconsistent among the Swift developers. It might be related to some refactoring of `Foundation` or other built-in frameworks method names, but it's just an assumption.

If you really need to keep the original name, you can explicitly give the name to the method with use of `NS_SWIFT_NAME` macro:

```objc
@interface ForkNewSession : NSObject

+ (NSInteger)StartFork NS_SWIFT_NAME(StartFork());

@end
```

In case the method has parameters, just follow standard Swift-selector grammar to describe them:

```objc
+ (NSInteger)StartForkWithInt:(NSInteger)intValue string:(NSString *_Nonnull)stringValue NS_SWIFT_NAME(StartForkWithInt(_:string:));
```

Comment: How does the syntax look when there are parameters?
Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089043/can-i-use-reserved-keywords-in-ns-swift-name), I know that only the argument label has to be specified. 
But what if you have two arguments? 

In the case of a function accepting CommandLine arguments (the two arguments are Int32 and UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>), how does it look?

Comment: Apple docs doesn't explain how to do it for methods :(

Comment: @NightFuryLxD I complemented my answer with example with parameters. You specify `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>` and `Int32` from Swift as `int8_t *_Nullable *_Nonnull` and `int32_t` correspondingly in Objective-C.